# How to display images in python simple gui from a api url

Tags: python, api, pysimplegui

I want to read a image from api, but I  am getting a error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I am trying to make a random meme generator

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import requests, json 



cutURL = 'https://meme-api-python.herokuapp.com/gimme'

imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(cutURL).content)["url"]

img = Image(requests.get(imageURL).content)




img_box = sg.Image(img)



window = sg.Window('', [[img_box]])
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:
        break
window.close()
```

```
Here is the response of the api 
postLink    "https://redd.it/yyjl2e"
subreddit   "dankmemes"
title   "Everything's fixed"
url "https://i.redd.it/put9bi0vjp0a1.jpg"
```

I tried using python simple gui module, IS there alternative way to make a random meme generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIL.Image` is a module, you can not call it by Image(...), maybe you need call it by Image.open(...). At the same, tkinter/PySimpleGUI cannot handle JPG image, so conversion to PNG image is required.

```py
from io import BytesIO
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image
import requests, json

def image_to_data(im):
    """
    Image object to bytes object.
    : Parameters
      im - Image object
    : Return
      bytes object.
    """
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        data = output.getvalue()
    return data

cutURL = 'https://meme-api-python.herokuapp.com/gimme'

imageURL = json.loads(requests.get(cutURL).content)["url"]
data = requests.get(imageURL).content
stream = BytesIO(data)
img = Image.open(stream)

img_box = sg.Image(image_to_data(img))

window = sg.Window('', [[img_box]], finalize=True)

# Check if the size of the window is greater than the screen
w1, h1 = window.size
w2, h2 = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
if w1>w2 or h1>h2:
    window.move(0, 0)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:
        break
window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Image.open(...)` - `Image` is a module, not a class.  You can find a tutorial in [the official PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html).

You may need to put the response content in a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object before you can use `Image.open` on it.  `BytesIO` is a file-like object that exists only in memory.  Most functions like `Image.open` that expect a file-like object will also accept `BytesIO` and `StringIO` (the text equivalent) objects.

Example:

```py
from io import BytesIO

def get_image(url):
    data = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)
    return Image.open(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with tk its simple and fast

```
def window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    panel = Label(root)
    panel.pack()
    img = None

    def updata():

        response = requests.get(https://meme-api-python.herokuapp.com/gimme)
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        img = img.resize((640, 480), Image.ANTIALIAS) #custom resolution
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        panel.config(image=img)
        panel.image = img
     
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.after(30, updata)

    updata()
    root.mainloop()
```